# How to tell pip3 to prefer download (and install) wheel files over the tar.gz when downloading and installing python3 packages

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, setuptools, setup.py, python-wheel

I'm a bit new to Python and all its "deployment" related tools: `pip3`,`setuptools`, `virtualenv` `wheel` etc, so I hope my question will make sense...anyways it is like so:

I have a Python3 project which is "managed" with virtual environment using `virtualenv` where all the projects' dependencies are "listed" within the project's `setup.py` file. The contents of the `setup.py` files are as follows:

```
setup(name="MyProjectName",
      version="0.1",
      description="Some description",
      url="someURL",
      author="My Name",
      author_email="someemail",
      license="MIT",
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=["robotframework", "paramiko"])
```

As you can see, the only 3rd party packages the project uses (explicitly) are `robotframework` & `paramiko`.

Now when I'm deploying the project, I do the following actions (in that order):

1. Create a virtual environment with the command:
   `virtualenv -p python3 virtualEnvFolderName`
2. Switching "into" the virtual environment like so (I'm deploying it on a Linux machine):
   `source virtualEnvFolderName/bin/activate`
3. Running the `setup.py` script with the `install` argument to "automatically" install all the project's dependencies with the following command:
   `python3 setup.py install`

--> Up until couple of days ago, all the 3rd party packages (and their "dependencies sub-packages") listed in the `setup.py` file where downloaded (and then installed) using their `whl` file, i.e. - for example:The output for the `paramiko` package installation would have been:

> Reading https://pypi.org/simple/paramiko/
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/80/74dace9e48b0ef923633dfb5e48798f58a168e4734bca8ecfaf839ba051a/paramiko-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=99f0179bdc176281d21961a003ffdb2ec369daac1a1007241f53374e376576cf
>   Best match: paramiko 2.6.0
>   Processing paramiko-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing paramiko-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl to

--> This way, the installation was very quick (~1-3 seconds per package).

Today, when I performed the same procedure, on the same machine (I'm quiet sure I did not change any settings on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine), for each package the `setup.py` tried to install, it installed "via" the `tar.gz` file (i.e. sources ?) and **NOT** using the `whl` file --> which takes MUCH longer since for some of the packages it actually builds (complies) all the "underlying C libraries". This "change" makes my "installation procedure" execution time increase from ~20 seconds to ~4 minutes.

My questions are:

a) How can I resolve this situation - preferably **without** changing the deployment procedure, i.e. - still perform the 3 steps mentioned above, taking into account that perhaps one or more of the commands will be slightly modified (the creation of the virtual environment and/or some additional argument in required to the `setup.py` ? ).

b) If I have no other option, then using a `pip3 install -r requirement.txt ...` "procedure" will also be good, if it also will use `whl` file(s) whenever applicable.

c) If I will need to "switch" my virtual environment "generator" to `venv` it is OK (and actually preferred, in case it will deploy the project in the "same" duration).

NOTES:
I tested it both on `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Ubuntu 18.04` machines with `Python 3.5` and `Python 3.6`  respectively.

Thanks !!

Comment: Found a solution? Is it still happening? I read through your question, but I can't point what the exact issue is. If nothing changed in your environment, then the installation should still behave in a similar fashion. Can you restrict the issue to one platform, one interpreter, and one package version? In the example of _paramiko_ there seems to be a _universal wheel_ available, so it is surprising if it's not used...

Comment: @sinoroc - Hi, I have not found a solution. To be more precised (as for your request) the package I seem to "have trouble" with it (i.e.- `pip3` downloads its `tar.gz` over the `.whl` file) is  the `PyNaCI` package. In addition, the platform `pip3` downloads the packages is Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit, with Python 3.6 interpreter. My "assumption", after viewing the "versions" page of the `PyNaCI` package (from https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/#files) is that due to the fact that there is no `_x6_64.whl` file for Python 3.6+, then it "falls back" to the tar.gz "flavor"). I wonder what can I do if so...?

Answer (score 1):

To install from wheel instead of tar.gz (source), you can now add the `--prefer-binairy` argument. This prefers binary packages over source packages, even if the source packages are newer.

Like this:

```
pip install jellyfish --prefer-binairy
```

From [the pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no *wheel* compatible with your environment (operating system, Python interpreter version, CPU bitness) for the [current version of the project *PyNaCl*](https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/1.3.0/#files). If you have a recent version of *pip*, the command [`path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip debug --verbose`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_debug/) should list the *tags* that are compatible with your environment, so that you can compare with the list of *wheels* available on *PyPI*.